# A way to accomplish @ConditionalOn*ANY*Class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot autoconfiguration to load a bean in the context in case there is at least one of 3 beans present.

I need something like:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnANYClass({ CreateHandler.class, UpdateHandler.class, DeleteHandler.class})
```

Any smart solution or out-of-the-box annotation for the logical OR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`AnyNestedCondition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/AnyNestedCondition.html) with one nested condition per class that you want to match.

Comment: Do I need o define a class explictly? Is there any closer way to provide it inline a la `@AnyNestedCondition({@ConditionalOnClass(A.class), @ConditionalOnClass(B.class)})` ?

Comment: Not out of the box, no

Comment: [You cannot have nested inline annotations without additional hacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38059047/476716)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting report from the very Spring Gitub Issue track:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5279