# Intellij @__(@Lazy) cannot find symbol

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I have a problem with building maven project in intellij

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol: class __
```

with annotation

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Lazy))
```

when I want to run project I got this error.
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: You are using the java 7 syntax, but I guess you are on java 8+.

Comment: Make sure you have configured the Lombok for the project. And have Lombok plugin enabled, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38059047/2000323

Comment: Running into this same issue. Any solution?